# React/Redux: get the user geolocation using a promise and dispatch the position to the action creator

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

In my `store.js` I'm trying to get the enduser geolocation from the browser, and then dispathc an action creator, but this doesn't occur.

```
function showPosition(position) {
    console.log("showPosition");
    //console.log(position);
    return position;
}

function getLocation() {
    // Get the current 'global' time from an API using Promise
    console.log("getLocation")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            console.log("Boolean navigator.getLocation:" + Boolean(navigator.geolocation))
            Promise.resolve(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition))
        } else {
            Promise.reject("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
        }
    })
}

function loadNearbyShops() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return getLocation().then(
            position => dispatch(getCoords(position))
        ).catch(
            error => console.log(error)
            );
    };
}

store.dispatch(loadNearbyShops())
```

But this doesn't trigger my action creator below

On the other hand, my `action creator` is defined as:

```
export function getCoords(position) {
    console.log(position)
    return {
        type: 'GET_LOCATION',
        long: position.coords.longitude,
        lat: position.coords.latitude
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the `getLocation` function to be:

```js
function getLocation() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
                showPosition(pos);
                resolve(pos);
            });
        } else {
            reject("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")
        }
    )};
}
```